# How to clear StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. While running the code on phone with SDK version 23 the app is stopped due to unexpected reasons. On checking Logcat it is showing error in `SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`

```
  02-09 20:55:17.833 15461-15461/com.example.android.pets E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
    02-09 20:55:18.082 15461-15461/com.example.android.pets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.android.pets, PID: 15461
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.pets/com.example.android.pets.CatalogActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
         Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.validateFilePath(ContextImpl.java:1926)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:571)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
            at com.example.android.pets.CatalogActivity.displayDatabaseInfo(CatalogActivity.java:68)
            at com.example.android.pets.CatalogActivity.onStart(CatalogActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1268)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6333)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2553)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
```

code:

```
private void displayDatabaseInfo() {
    // To access our database, we instantiate our subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper
    // and pass the context, which is the current activity.
    Cursor cursor;
    try (SQLiteDatabase db = mPetDbHelper.getReadableDatabase()) {

        String[] projection = {PetContract.PetEntry._ID, PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED, PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER, PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT};

        // Create and/or open a database to read from it


        // Perform this raw SQL query "S  \
        // ELECT * FROM pets"
        // to get a Cursor that contains all rows from the pets table.
        cursor = db.query(PetContract.PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    TextView displayView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_pet);

    try {
        // Display the number of rows in the Cursor (which reflects the number of rows in the
        // pets table in the database).

        displayView.setText("The pets table contains:" + cursor.getCount() + "pets.\n\n");
        displayView.append(PetContract.PetEntry._ID + "-" + PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME + "-" + PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED + "-" + PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER + "-" + PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT);

        int idColummnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetContract.PetEntry._ID);
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME);
        int breedColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED);
        int genderColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER);
        int weightColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){

            int currentID = cursor.getInt(idColummnIndex);
            String currentName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
            String currentBreed = cursor.getString(breedColumnIndex);
            int currentGender = cursor.getInt(genderColumnIndex);
            int currentWeight = cursor.getInt(weightColumnIndex);

            displayView.append("\n" + currentID + "-" + currentName + "-" + currentBreed + "-" +currentGender + "-" + currentWeight);

        }

    } finally {
        // Always close the cursor when you're done reading from it. This releases all its
        // resources and makes it invalid.
        cursor.close();
    }
}`
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and follow this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post relavent code... You have error for "String.charAt()" method. But there is no such line in code that you have post.  If you have use thid method then put if condition before this line to check if string if not null.

Comment: The error is at line: SQLiteDatabase db = mPetDbHelper.getReadableDatabase()

Comment: he said provide your code more... the problem is you took a value on index 0 but the size is 0.

Comment: Obviously the problem is not here ... but in helper class ... you pass empty string as db name

Comment: show us this activity too, `com.example.android.pets.CatalogActivity.displayDatabaseInfo(CatalogActivity.java:68)`